# Oracle sorting connect by prior hierarchically

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, connect-by

I have a table where there is a parent/child relationship defined, but there is no way to sort via hierarchical level.

```
For example consider this:
   empid  managerid   name 
    js       hd      George
    hd       ab       Mary
    hs       js       Tom
    ab       xx       John
```

Since i cannot use ORDER SIBLINGS BY for sorting in hierarchical way, how will i be able to sort this in hierarchical way like below?

```
     empid managerid  name 
     ab       xx       John
     hd       ab       Mary
     js       hd      George
     hs       js       Tom
```

Comment: confused. isn't the way you listed it the default way for CONNECT BY?

Answer (score 9):

It would have been helpful to show us the queries you have attempted so far. It sounds like there is a misunderstanding somewhere.

For your very small sample data `Eng. Samer T`'s answer is correct.  You don't need an `order by` clause.  Oracle guarantees that rows will be returned in a hierarchical order in a `connect by` query. [Oracle documentation on Hierarchical Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm):

> 5. Oracle returns the rows in the order shown in Figure 9-1. In the diagram, ***children appear below their parents***.

What is ***not*** guaranteed is how rows within a same hierarchy level (siblings) will be sorted.  But because your sample data only has a single child for every level, this effectively doesn't matter.

---

However, let's consider an example with a bit more data so that we have siblings.

```
create table Employee (
  empid varchar2(50) not null,
  managerid varchar2(50) not null,
  name varchar2(50) not null
)
/

insert into Employee (empid, managerid, name) values ('js', 'hd', 'George');
insert into Employee (empid, managerid, name) values ('hd', 'ab', 'Mary');
insert into Employee (empid, managerid, name) values ('hs', 'js', 'Tom');
insert into Employee (empid, managerid, name) values ('ww', 'js', 'Waldo');
insert into Employee (empid, managerid, name) values ('ab', 'xx', 'John');
insert into Employee (empid, managerid, name) values ('ab2', 'xx', 'Other manager');
insert into Employee (empid, managerid, name) values ('st', 'ab2', 'Stan');
insert into Employee (empid, managerid, name) values ('lee', 'ab2', 'Lee');

alter table employee
add constraint employee_pk
primary key (empid)
/
```

If I then run the following `connect by` query ***without*** an `order by` clause:

```
select t.*, level
from employee t
start with t.managerid = 'xx'
connect by prior t.empid = t.managerid
```

I get ([SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9538c6/1)):

```
empid   managerid   name          level
-----   ---------   ----          -----
ab      xx          John            1
hd      ab          Mary            2
js      hd          George          3
hs      js          Tom             4
ww      js          Waldo           4
ab2     xx          Other manager   1
lee     ab2         Lee             2
st      ab2         Stan            2
```

Notice how the hierarchy is respected, this is guaranteed. However, for siblings, the order is not guaranteed. For instance, there is no guarantee that `John` will *always* be listed before `Other manager`, that `Tom` will be listed before `Waldo`, or that `Lee` will be listed before `Stan`.

If you want to guarantee ordering within siblings, but without breaking the order of the hierarchy, that's precisely what the `order siblings by` clause is for.

So I don't know why you said:

> i cannot use `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` for sorting in hierarchical way

Because, the [Oracle documentation on Hierarchical Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm) pretty much states the opposite:

> In a hierarchical query, do not specify either `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY`, as they will override the hierarchical order of the `CONNECT BY` results. If you want to order rows of siblings of the same parent, then use the `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` clause.

Notice how it specifically recommends the use of `order siblings by` to sort siblings *without* breaking the hierarchical order of the results.

So let's say I want my results ordered hierarchically, but having siblings ordered alphabetically by descending name.  Then I could adjust my earlier query to:

```
select t.*, level
from employee t
start with t.managerid = 'xx'
connect by prior t.empid = t.managerid
order siblings by name desc
```

And my results become ([SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9538c6/2)):

```
empid   managerid   name          level
-----   ---------   ----          -----
ab2     xx          Other manager   1
st      ab2         Stan            2
lee     ab2         Lee             2
ab      xx          John            1
hd      ab          Mary            2
js      hd          George          3
ww      js          Waldo           4
hs      js          Tom             4
```

Notice how the hierarchy is still respected. But siblings `John` and `Other manager` are reordered so that `Other manager`'s entire tree of results is listed before `John`'s. Also, `Waldo` will now always appear before `Tom`, and `Stan` will always appear before `Lee`.

Answer (score 0):

default "connect by" clause will return the result.

just start with head, I assume that 'xx' means no manager.

```
select t.*, t.rowid from emp_table t
start with managerid = 'xx'
connect by prior empid = managerid
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.... ORDER BY level gave the result i wanted. I wasn't knowing level is already defined in Oracle.